# input value needs to split

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a single Input text sending multiply values to store in the database

The input value is like this

```
2015-10-26, 2015-10-27, 2015-10-28
```

```vb
date = Request.Form("datumtid")
Conn.Execute("Insert Into speldagar(date) Values('"& date &"')")
```

But i need every date to be added in a singel line
exemple

```vb
date = Request.Form("datumtid")
Conn.Execute("Insert Into speldagar(date) Values(2015-10-26)")
Conn.Execute("Insert Into speldagar(date) Values(2015-10-27)")
```

How can can I do this the best way?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server you can use an `INSERT` with a `SELECT ... UNION ALL` to stitch all the values into one database call, rather then making multiple database calls in a loop.

Comment: Dynamically build the statement using a `For Next` loop based on splitting the `Request.Form("datumtid")`. This also allows you prepare the parameters beforehand so you can execute the statement using a `ADODB.Command` to avoid SQL Injection threats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a single input string of the form `2015-10-26, 2015-10-27, 2015-10-28` you need to [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5) the string at commas and [trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c623wz83) whitespace from the resulting tokens:

```
dates = Request.Form("datumtid")
For Each d In Split(dates, ",")
  Conn.Execute "INSERT INTO speldagar (date) VALUES ('" & Trim(d) & "')"
Next
```

Theoretically you could do a `Split(dates, ", ")` (i.e. split at commas followed by a space) without trimming, but that would require correctly formatted input. It's more robust to split at delimiters and then trim the resulting array elements.

Also, I'd *strongly* recommend *against* building your SQL query by string concatenation, because building queries that way makes you vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use a [prepared statement](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200190) to avoid this:

```
qry = "INSERT INTO speldagar (date) VALUES (?)"
dates = Request.Form("datumtid")
For Each d In Split(dates, ",")
  Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
  cmd.CommandText = qry
  Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@date" , 135, 1, 0, Trim(d))
  cmd.Parameters.Append param
  cmd.Execute
Next
```

Note that, as @Lankymart pointed out, this still is a suboptimal approach, because it does multiple inserts, which doesn't perform too well. Something like this might work better:

```
baseQry = "INSERT INTO speldagar (date) VALUES "

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn

dates = Split(Request.Form("datumtid"), ",")
ReDim fields(UBound(dates))
For i = 0 To UBound(dates)
  fields(i) = "(?)"
  Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@date" , 135, 1, 0, Trim(dates(i)))
  cmd.Parameters.Append param
Next
cmd.CommandText = baseQry & Join(fields, ",")
cmd.Execute
```

Can't test it, though, since I don't have access to an SQL Server.

Comment: It worth noting this method will incur multiple calls to the database. Personally I never recommend making calls to a database inside a loop. Also `adDate` (7) is not in SQL Server the data type `datetime`, should use `adDBTimeStamp` (135).

Comment: As long as your parameter data type is set correctly there is no need to `CDate()` the value as SQL Server will do the cast and return an error if it fails, rather then manipulating the data beforehand which can have unexpected results.

Comment: Not sure without testing it *(depends on the SQL Server version)*, but getting closer to my approach.

Comment: Just tested it, nice approach will work in SQL Server 2008 above - See [Table Value Constructor (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382(v=sql.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some idea how to go about it.

```vb
Dim datumtids, data, sql
Dim item, items

datumtids = Request.Form("datumtid") & ""
data = Split(dataumtids, ",")
sql = ""

Dim cmd, conn, affected
conn = "..." 'The database connection string

If IsArray(data) Then
  Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

  sql = sql & "INSERT INTO speldagar ([date])" & vbCrLf
  items = UBound(data)
  For item = LBound(data) To items
    sql = sql & "SELECT ?" & vbCrLf
    Call cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@item" & item, adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 8))
    If item < items Then sql = sql & "UNION ALL" & vbCrLf
  Next
  cmd.CommandText = sql
  Call cmd.Execute(affected, data, adExecuteNoRecords)
  Set cmd = Nothing
End If
```

<sup>* *This code to is entirely pseudo coded and untested*</sup>

The SQL should be dynamically built and the `sql` variable output should look like this once finished;

```sql
INSERT INTO speldagar ([date])
SELECT ?
UNION ALL
SELECT ?
UNION ALL
SELECT ?
```

Couple of things to point out about this code.

- Avoids the use of `date` as a variable name. You especially want to do this if you intend on using `Date()` function anywhere in the code.
- Using `ADODB.Command` object to build parameterised query, this avoids the possibility of SQL Injection into code like;

  ```
   sql = "Insert Into speldagar(date) Values('"& date &"')"
  ```
- We can build our parameters at the same time as we build up the SQL statement, this is simple because all of the data is the same type *(`adDBTimeStamp`)*.
- This is an `INSERT` SQL command so we are not expecting a resultset, we can make the call more efficient by specifying `adExecuteNoRecords` in the `.Execute()` method.

---

#### Useful links

- [Carl Prothman - Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx)
  *My definitive "go to" guide for data type mapping in ADO, it's never steered me wrong.*
- [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417073339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml)
  *If your are having issues with `adCmdText`, `adDBTimeStamp`, `adParamInput` and other built-in ADO constants you probably need to have them imported. `METADATA` is by far the cleanest way of doing this.*

Comment: The point of this answer is to give the OP an idea how to approach the problem, not do it for them. It is entirely pseudo coded / untested. Hopefully it will give the OP a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

I found a simpler solution that works :)

```
myVariable = Request.Form("datumtid")

myArray = Split(myVariable,",")

For i = LBound(myArray) TO UBound(myArray)

Conn.Execute("Insert Into speldagar(date) Values('"& myArray(i) &"')")

Next
```

Thank you for you answer :)

Comment: So you ignore all the advice given and post that?

Comment: Basically that is @ansgar-wiechers first answer but without any of the warnings being heeded. Send me the web address and I'll inject something nasty into your SQL database for you. Unbelievable!!

Comment: I find this *"I found a simpler solution that works :)"* really insulting, just because it works doesn't mean you should do it! You said *"How can can I do this the best way?"* not "How can I do this the unsafest simplest way possible?" You should seriously re-consider your approach.